# GetAuthenticationStateAsync() in Custom AuthenticationStateProvider not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have made a class called CustomAuthenticationStateProvider that inherits from Authentication state provider. Right now its very basic for testing, but I am going to have it read from a JWT in local storage later for claims.

Here is the code right now:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private ClaimsPrincipal _anonymous = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

    private ClaimsPrincipal _user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_user));
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        //make claims for an admin user and return that as the authentication state
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Jeff"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Custom");

        _user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        _user = _anonymous;

        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
    }
```

Here is my app.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

and in my program.cs
I have:
`builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>(); builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(s => s.GetRequiredService<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>());`

and

`app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseAuthorization();`

then to test inside of my navbar I put this:

```
    <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
            Auth
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            Not Auth
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
```

I tried implementing this same code inside a new blazor server application and it seemed to work as expected. In that application I can set a breakpoint at the return in GetAuthenticationStateAsync() and it will break when the app launches, that is not the case in the actual app I have been working on. Unless I call the login out logout function GetAuthenticationStateAsync() is never called.

Comment: "I tried implementing this same code inside a new blazor server application and it seemed to work as expected. "  [Polite] You need to figure out the differences.  We can't find problems in code we can't see.  This repo [of mine] provides a `VerySimpleAuthenticationProvider` that switches identities through a select control in the layout.  It demos various authorization techniques - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.Authorization

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thats more what I was asking, just showing code to show that all of the basic things are there, like the CascadingAuthenticationState. Frankly, I don't know where to look for the culprit.

I don't have any idea as to why its not calling that function to get the state.

Comment: Understand, I've been there too.  I'm just reviewing your code at the moment.  Take a look at my code in the Repo, something may click!

Comment: Net version? What render mode?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I found it, I will try and figure out how to post a solution after this comment (first time actually using stack overflow). (also .net 6, server render mode, no prerendering). The problem was in my program.cs my adding the AuthenticationStateProvider to DI was before the line builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(); moving it after solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my issue was with the location of

```
        builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(s => s.GetRequiredService<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>());
```

I had placed it before the line

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
```

and I guess it needs to come after for it to work correctly.

Hope this can help someone else if they encounter the same issue.

Comment: Known issue.  `builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();` adds all the default services.  This will overwrite your earlier adding of the custom provider.  I even have it as a comment somewhere in my own code and in code I've provided for a similar question in the past.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Forgive me, what should I have searched to find that issue?

Comment: No forgiving needed.   On searching, SO isn't the best at finding results.  I often have difficulty finding answers I wrote a few months ago.   I tried searching for the last time I or someone else answered a question on the issue but I couldn't find it!